# Find the swapped nodes in binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

Two of the nodes of a Binary Search Tree are swapped.

Input Tree:

```
     10
    /  \
   5    8
  / \
 2   20
```

In the above tree, nodes 20 and 8 must be swapped to  fix the tree.

Output tree:

```
     10
    /  \
   5    20
  / \
 2   8
```

I followed the solution given in [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fix-two-swapped-nodes-of-bst/). But I feel the solution is incorrect because:

**As per the site:**

> 1. The swapped nodes are not adjacent in the inorder traversal of the BST.
>
>    For example, Nodes 5 and 25 are swapped in **`{3 5 7 8 10 15 20 25}`**.
>      The inorder traversal of the given tree is **`3 25 7 8 10 15 20 5`**  If we
>      observe carefully, during inorder traversal, we find node 7 is smaller
>      than the previous visited node 25. Here save the context of node 25
>      (previous node). Again, we find that node 5 is smaller than the
>      previous node 20. This time, we save the context of node 5 ( current
>      node ). Finally swap the two node’s values.

So my point is if it is considering 25 because it is greater than 7 than it should consider 20 as well because it is also greater than 5. So is this correct solution or I am missing something?

Comment: @downvoter don't behave like a looser , dare to comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is considering 25 because it is greater than 7. But, it should **not** consider 20 as well because it is also greater than 5. Instead, it should consider 5 because it is less than 20.

This example is not very good, because the position of 5 in the original array is the last one. Let's consider a sorted array `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`. Swap 2 and 4, then we get `{1, 4, 3, 2, 5}`. If two elements (not adjacent) in a sorted array is swapped, for all pairs like `(A[i], A[i+1])`, there will be exactly two pairs that is in wrong order, namely descending order. In the case of `{1, 4, 3, 2, 5}`, we have pair `(4, 3)`, and pair `(3, 2)`. Suppose we have pair `(A[p], A[p+1])` and pair `(A[q], A[q+1])`, such that `A[p] > A[p+1]` and `A[q] > A[q+1]`, we can claim that it is `A[p]` and `A[q+1]` being swapped. In the case of `{1, 4, 3, 2, 5}`, it is 4 and 2 being swapped.

Now come back to the example `3 25 7 8 10 15 20 5`, in which `25, 7` and `20 5` are the only two pairs in wrong order. Then 25 and 5 are the two elements being swapped.

Comment: `Suppose we have pair (A[p], A[p+1]) and pair (A[q], A[q+1]), such that A[p] > A[p+1] and A[q] > A[q+1], we can claim that it is A[p] and A[q+1] being swapped` how can you prove your point.

Answer (score 1):

Following @jeffreys' notation,

> if we have pair (A[p], A[p+1]) and pair (A[q], A[q+1]), such that A[p] > A[p+1] and A[q] > A[q+1], we can claim that it is A[p] and A[q+1] being swapped

You know that there's only a single swap, that would create either 2 discrepancies in the sorted order, or only one if they're adjacent. Let's say p < q, so the A[p],A[p+1] is the first descending pair, and the q's are the second.

- If there's no second couple, than swapping the first couple would fix the tree, that's the easy part. Otherwise we know there are two non-adjacent nodes.
- Out of the A[p] and A[p+1] let's say that A[p+1] was the one out of place. Since this is the first couple we would have to move A[p+1] forward towards the second couple, but that means that it's still going to be smaller than the earlier A[p] that stayed in place, so we would not create a sorted array. We must therefore chose A[p].
- Same goes for the A[q] and A[q+1], let's say that A[q] was out of place, that means we'll have to move it backwards, and it would still be larger than A[q+1] appearing later, again breaking sort.