# Find and revert the swapped nodes in a binary search tree, time requires O(n) and space requires O(h) where h refers to tree depth

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, binary-search-tree

for more detail about the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884029/find-the-swapped-nodes-in-binary-search-tree)

though it's easy to just swap two node's value in the bst, if it requires us to change node instead of its value, it is a little bit hard. [In this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20614575/how-to-swap-two-nodes-in-binary-tree) author(Graham Asher) have list some situations, but it is not fully consider.

Changing two nodes in a tree, we need to consider three question:

1. is `node1` or `node2` the `head` of the tree?
2. is `node1` father of `node2` or `node2` is father of `node1`?
3. `node1` and `node2` is `leftChild` or `rightChild`

Comment: There is no question here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `kotlin` solution:

**TreeNode defines**

```kotlin
class TreeNode(var value: Int, var leftNode: TreeNode? = null, var rightNode: TreeNode? = null) {
    component object {

        fun serialization(root: TreeNode): String {
            var result = ""
            var stack = ArrayDeque<TreeNode>()
            stack.add(root)
            result = result.plus(root.value).plus(",")

            while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                var node = stack.removeFirst();
                result = if (node.leftNode != null) {
                    stack.add(node.leftNode!!)
                    result.plus(node.leftNode!!.value).plus(",")
                } else {
                    result.plus("#,")
                }

                result = if (node.rightNode != null) {
                    stack.add(node.rightNode!!)
                    result.plus(node.rightNode!!.value).plus(",")
                } else {
                    result.plus("#,")
                }
            }
            return result.dropLast(1)
        }
        fun deserialization(str: String): TreeNode {
            var values = str.split(",")

            var intValue = stoi(values[0]) ?: 0
            var root = TreeNode(intValue)

            var currentNode = root
            var stack = ArrayDeque<TreeNode>()

            var idx = 1
            while (idx < values.size) {
                var v = stoi(values[idx])

                if (v != null) {
                    currentNode.leftNode = TreeNode(v)
                    stack.add(currentNode.leftNode!!)
                }
                idx += 1
                if (idx < values.size) {
                    v = stoi(values[idx])
                    if (v != null) {
                        currentNode.rightNode = TreeNode(v)
                        stack.add(currentNode.rightNode!!)
                    }
                    currentNode = stack.removeFirst()
                    idx += 1
                }
            }
            return root
        }    
    }
    override fun toString(): String {
        var left = if (leftNode != null) leftNode!!.value.toString() else ""
        var right = if (rightNode != null) rightNode!!.value.toString() else ""

        return "value: $value, left: $left, right: $right"
    }
}
```

**Solution**

```
class FindBSTErrorNodes {
    companion object {
        fun find(head: TreeNode): ArrayList<TreeNode?> {
            var errNodes = arrayListOf<TreeNode?>(null, null)

            var stack = ArrayDeque<TreeNode>()
            var pre: TreeNode? = null
            var cur: TreeNode? = head

            var findCount = 0
            while (!stack.isEmpty() || cur != null) {
                if (cur != null) {
                    stack.add(cur)
                    cur = cur.leftNode
                } else {
                    cur = stack.removeLast()
                    if (pre != null && pre.value > head.value) {
                        errNodes[0] = errNodes[0] ?: pre
                        errNodes[1] = cur
                        findCount += 1
                        if (findCount >= 2) {
                            return errNodes
                        }
                    }
                    pre = cur
                    cur = cur.rightNode
                }
            }

            return errNodes
        }

        fun findParent(head: TreeNode, node: TreeNode?): TreeNode? {
            if (node == null) {
                return null
            }

            var stack = ArrayDeque<TreeNode>()
            var cur: TreeNode? = head
            while (stack != null || cur != null) {
                if (cur != null) {
                    stack.add(cur)
                    cur = cur.leftNode
                } else {
                    cur = stack.removeLast()
                    if (cur.leftNode == node || cur.rightNode == node)
                        return cur
                    cur = cur.rightNode
                }
            }

            return null
        }

        fun swapTwoNode(head: TreeNode, node1: TreeNode, node2: TreeNode): TreeNode {
            var node1Parent = findParent(head, node1)
            var node1Left = node1.leftNode
            var node1Right = node1.rightNode
            var node2Parent = findParent(head, node2)
            var node2Left = node2.leftNode
            var node2Right = node2.rightNode

            // in case node1 is the head of a binary search tree
            when {
                node1 == head -> {
                    node1.leftNode = node2Left
                    node1.rightNode = node2Right
                    when {
                        node1.leftNode == node2 -> { // it should never be happen in swapped binary search tree
                            node2.leftNode = node1
                            node2.rightNode = node1Right
                        }
                        node1.rightNode == node2 -> {
                            node2.leftNode = node1Left
                            node2.rightNode = node1
                        }
                        else -> {
                            node2.leftNode = node1Left
                            node2.rightNode = node1Left
                            if (node2Parent!!.leftNode == node2) {
                                node2Parent!!.leftNode = node1
                            } else {
                                node2Parent!!.rightNode = node1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return node2
                }
                node2 == head -> {
                    node2.leftNode = node1Left
                    node2.rightNode = node1Right
                    when {
                        node2.leftNode == node1 -> { // it should never be happen in swapped binary search tree
                            node1.leftNode = node2
                            node1.rightNode = node2Right
                        }
                        node2.rightNode == node1 -> {
                            node1.leftNode = node2Left
                            node1.rightNode = node2
                        }
                        else -> {
                            node1.leftNode = node2Left
                            node1.rightNode = node2Left
                            if (node1Parent!!.leftNode == node1) {
                                node1Parent!!.leftNode = node2
                            } else {
                                node1Parent!!.rightNode = node2
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return node1
                }
                else -> {
                    when {
                        node1 == node2Parent -> {
                            if (node1Parent!!.leftNode == node1) {
                                node1Parent.leftNode = node2
                            } else {
                                node1Parent.rightNode = node2
                            }
                            node1.leftNode = node2.leftNode
                            node1.rightNode = node2.rightNode
                            if (node2Parent.leftNode == node2) { // it should never be happen in swapped binary search tree
                                node2.leftNode = node1
                                node2.rightNode = node1Right
                            } else {
                                node2.leftNode = node1.leftNode
                                node2.rightNode = node1
                            }
                        }
                        node1Parent == node2 -> {
                            if (node2Parent!!.leftNode == node2) {
                                node2Parent.leftNode = node1
                            } else {
                                node2Parent.rightNode = node1
                            }
                            node2.leftNode = node1.leftNode
                            node2.rightNode = node1.rightNode
                            if (node1Parent.leftNode == node1) { // it should never be happen in swapped binary search tree
                                node1.leftNode = node2
                                node1.rightNode = node2Right
                            } else {
                                node1.leftNode = node2.leftNode
                                node1.rightNode = node2
                            }
                        }
                        else -> {
                            node1.leftNode = node2Left
                            node1.rightNode = node2Right
                            node2.leftNode = node1Left
                            node2.rightNode = node1Right
                            if (node1Parent!!.leftNode == node1) {
                                node1Parent.leftNode = node2
                            } else {
                                node1Parent.rightNode = node2
                            }
                            if (node2Parent!!.leftNode == node2) {
                                node2Parent.leftNode = node1
                            } else {
                                node2Parent.rightNode = node1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return head
        }
    }
}
```

and here a simple **Test case**

```
fun main() {
    var head = TreeSerialization.deserialization("3,5,4,1,#,#,2")
    MorrisRetrieve.pre(head)
    var errNodes = FindBSTErrorNodes.find(head)
    println(errNodes[0])
    println(errNodes[1])

    println(FindBSTErrorNodes.findParent(head, errNodes[0]))
    println(FindBSTErrorNodes.findParent(head, errNodes[1]))

    var newHead = FindBSTErrorNodes.swapTwoNode(head, errNodes[0]!!, errNodes[1]!!)
    println(TreeSerialization.serialization(newHead))
}
```